# Python: How do I take two different column inputs from the user and return the value of another column?

Tags: python

[image]

Using the first row as an example, let's say the user types in Arsenal and Leicester City. How do I get the code to match the inputted teams to "home_team" and "away_team" in the table and finally return the value 'H' which is from the column 'result' ?

I tried doing

x = input("Enter Home Team: ")
y = input("\nEnter Away Team: ")

def f(x,y):
return df.loc[df['Col 1'] == x and df['Col 2'] == y, 'Col 3'].item()

But nothing turns up.

Comment: please use code tags (three backticks) surrounding your code

Comment: I see that you have `defined` your function, but not seeing how you are `calling` your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simplified and relevant version of your dataframe.
Say your dataframe is named (**df**):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'home_team':['Arsenal', 'Watford', 'Chelsea'],
                   'away_team':['Leicester City','Liverpool','Burnley'],
                   'result':['H','D','A']})
```

Then you could extract the results from your dataframe in the way that you were trying to do it - like this:

```py
# Function to extract result
def f(x,y): return df.loc[(df['home_team'] == x) & (df['away_team'] == y), ['result']]

# Get the teams from the user
x = input("Enter Home Team: ") 
y = input("\nEnter Away Team: ")

# Print the result
print(f(x,y))
```

And the output when you select `Arsenal` for the home team and `Leicester City` for the away team is:

```
  result
0      H
```